# PHPExcel can not import the excel file to database

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to use phpExcel to get the import excel and insert into database, however,  i encounter the error.It seems that the array of correct entries can not insert into database.I have extract the codes and posted here, It is long indeed and it is tired to read with, so I will vote up for any people have answer the question.

Thank you very much for kindly help.

This part is for check error and duplication and obtain a valid list:

```
<body>

<?
session_start();

$file='../excelUpload/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/'.$_POST['excel'];
include '../plugin/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($ext=='xlsx')
$readerType='Excel2007';
elseif ($ext=='xls')
$readerType='Excel5';
elseif ($ext=='csv')
$readerType='CSV';

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readerType);
$PHPExcel = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());

$pattern="/^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/";

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
$testMail = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($head, $row)->getValue();
if (preg_match($pattern,$testMail))
$mailColumn=$head;
}}
if(!isset($mailColumn))
{die('No email column detected, please check your file and import again.');}


$invaild[] = NULL ;
$email[] = NULL ;
$duplicate[] = NULL ;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();

    if ($y == $mailColumn && !preg_match($pattern,$val))
    {$invaild[]=$row;}
    elseif ($y == $mailColumn && in_array($val,$email))
    {$duplicate[]=$val;
    $duplicate[]=$row;}
    //elseif (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild) )
    //{echo $val;}

    if ($y == $mailColumn)
    {$email[]=$val;
    $email=array_unique($email);}

  }
}
$invaild=array_unique($invaild);
?>

<!-- To Show mail import result -->
<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1><?echo $_POST['excel'].' Result';?></h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>
   <div id="container">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2" class="display" id="viewImport">
<thead>
<tr>

<?
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
if ($head==$mailColumn)
echo "<th field='col'$head> Email address </th>";
else
echo "<th field='col'$head><input id='$head' name='$head' class='required' value='Input Header' size='1'/> </th>";
}
?>
</tr>
</thead>

<?
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
        if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
            $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();
            echo "<td>";
            if (!$val)
            echo "-";
            else
            echo $val;
            echo "</td>";}
        }
    echo "</tr>";   
    }



?>

</table>
</div>


<form id="insertResult" method="post" action="excelSQL.php" >
<br><br><br>
<input type="hidden" id="file" name="file" value="<?echo $file;?>" />
<label>Insert into list:</label>
<input id="listName" name="listName"/>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert into Database"/>
</form>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This part is for insert into database:

```
<body>

<?
session_start();
include("../connection/conn.php");
$file=$_POST['file'];
include ("../plugin/excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ($ext=='xlsx')
$readerType='Excel2007';
elseif ($ext=='xls')
$readerType='Excel5';

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readerType);
$PHPExcel = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn());

$pattern="/^[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$/";

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
$testMail = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($head, $row)->getValue();
if (preg_match($pattern,$testMail))
$mailColumn=$head;
}}
if(!isset($mailColumn))
{die('No email column detected, please check your file and import again.');}


$invaild[] = NULL ;
$email[] = NULL ;
$duplicate[] = NULL ;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
    $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();

    if ($y == $mailColumn && !preg_match($pattern,$val))
    {$invaild[]=$row;}
    elseif ($y == $mailColumn && in_array($val,$email))
    {$duplicate[]=$val;
    $duplicate[]=$row;}
    //elseif (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild) )
    //{echo $val;}

    if ($y == $mailColumn)
    {$email[]=$val;
    $email=array_unique($email);}

  }
}
$invaild=array_unique($invaild);

for ($head = 0; $head < $highestColumn; $head++){
    if ($head != $mailColumn)
    {echo $_POST[$head];
    $sql="INSERT INTO subatt (AttID,AttName) VALUES ('','$_POST[$head]')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }}
    else 
    echo "email";
     }
?>


<div id="stylized" class="view">
<h1><?echo $file.' Result';?></h1> 
<p>Import from spreadsheet files</p>


<?

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
        if (!in_array($row,$duplicate) && !in_array($row,$invaild)){
            $val = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($y, $row)->getValue();
            if (!$val)
            {$sql="INSERT INTO subdata (DataID,DataContent) VALUES ('','')";}
            else
            $sql="INSERT INTO subdata (DataID,DataContent) VALUES ('','$val')";
                if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
                 {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT AttID FROM subatt WHERE AttName='$_POST[$y]'");
            if (!$result) 
            {die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());}
            $attID = mysql_result($result, 0);


            $sql="INSERT INTO subscriber (SubID,AttID,DataID) VALUES ('',$attID,'')";
                if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
                 {
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                }
        }
    }



?>

<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `i encounter the error` please write the error, what kind of error. It always help to solve the problem

Comment: You'd be better to use $readerType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file); than to trust the user input of the filename for identifying the file type and the reader to use... also uset try/catch blocks: PHPExcel throws exceptions that can help identify problems

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have a DataID in your queries. Why is it always empty? Is there is any unique/primary index?

I'd like to know what's the exact error too please